# Prove that $\frac{m!}{200}\neq50x^2+51x+13$ and is my working correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial, square-numbers

Where $m$ and $x$ any real non-negative interger values. Prove that $$\frac{m!}{200}\neq50x^2+51x+13$$
Where $m!\geq20$

I understand that it may link into a trivial part of Brocard's problem.
$$\frac{m!}{200}\neq50x^2+51x+13$$$$200(50x^2 + 51x + 13) + 1 = m!+1$$
$$200(50x^2 + 51x + 13) + 1 = (100x + 51)^2$$

**The thing I'm working on is below**
Assuming that $\frac{m!}{200}=50x^2+51x+13$

Because $m\geq20$: $m!$ is divisible by $3$. Therefore $\frac{m!}{200}$ is divisible by $3$. Therefore $50x^2+51x+13$ is divisible by 3. You can apply this for any prime (apart from $5$).
Therefore $50x^2+51x+13$ divides up to $m$ where $m$ doesn't divide by $5$ or $2$.

**Expansion-I'm not sure if this is the correct way of going throught this**
Using similar methods from the one above :Because $m\geq20$: $m!$ is divisible by $13$. Therefore $\frac{m!}{200}$ is divisible by $13$.Therefore $\frac{m!}{200}-13$ is divisible by $13$. Therefore $50x^2+51x$ is divisible by $13$.

**Because $50x^2+51x$ is divisible by 13 , $x$ must be divisble by $13$.**

**A possible continuation:**

Let's call $13y=x$ because $x$ is divisble by 13 $\therefore$ $50((13y)^2)+51(13y)+13=\frac{m!}{200}$ This equals $8450y^2+663y+13=\frac{m!}{200}$. For ease I will use two fractions. $$13(650y^2+51y+1)=\frac{m!}{200}$$$$650y^2+51y+1=\frac{\frac{m!}{200}}{13}$$
$$650y^2+51y=\frac{\frac{m!}{200}}{13}-1$$
$$13(50y^2)+17(3y)=\frac{\frac{m!}{200}}{13}-1$$
$$$$
To be continued...
if $m\geq26$ $m!$ is divisible by 169.

Comment: Considering $m\ge17$, we can see that $51 \mid m!$, but this still allows $x\in\{8,25,26,43\} \bmod 51$

Comment: @Joffan I've added the fact that $\frac{m!}{200}$ divides by $m$ where $m$ doesn't divide by $2$ or $5$. This is the same as $50x^2+51x+13$.

Comment: "Because $50x^2+51x$ is divisible by $13$ , $x$ must be divisble by $13$." is wrong. $50x+51$ can be divisible by $13$.

Comment: @didgogns Prove that $50x+51$ can be divisible by 13. I'm thinking you are right.

Comment: A simple calculation shows that $50x+51 \equiv 0\pmod {13}$ is equivalent to $x \equiv 6\pmod {13}$.

Comment: Yeah thanks. I'll have to rewrite my continuation . @didgogns

Comment: Surely the fact that $50x^2+51x+13=(2x+1)(25x+13)$ must help.  For one thing, since $m\ge20$ implies $m!/200$ has a large power of $2$, $x$ must be odd. So writing $x=2u-1$ we get $m!/200=4u(50u-12)=8u(25u-6)$.  It's clear that $u$ must be divisible by largish powers of $2$ and $3$ and by $5^2$ (at least).  Beyond that, though, it's less clear what can be said.

Comment: @BarryCipra First thank you for comment. I think one can prove that $X$ ends in a $7$. That what makes what are you saying true. $x=2u-1$$~\frac{x+1}{2}=u$ therefore $u$ end in a $4$.

Comment: @PintOfMilk, I made a serious mistake.  Writing $x=2u-1$ gives $m!/200=2(4u-1)(25u-6)$, instead of what I said. So **only the first two sentences of my comment are meaningful** (boldface to attract attention). Sorry!

Comment: @BarryCipra don't worry - look @ my profile for a ton of mistakes. Now onto the problem. I think $m!/400=(4u-1)(25u-6)$ is better but we may have to increase $m\geq20$ (I'll do that later) from $20$.  I have an alternative idea - unfortunately I am only a math fan but I wonder if you could do it. It is however complicated. First I wish to prove $x$ ends in a $7$. $m!/200=50x^2+51x+13$$~~m! /200$ ends in a $0$. $m!/200~-13$  ends in a 7. That equals $50x^2+51x$ ends in a 0. Because $50x^2$ ends in a 0. $51x$ must end in a 7. $\therefore x $ ends in a 7

Comment: @PintOfMilk, and if you look at *my* profile, you'll see I literally wrote the book on misteaks!

Comment: @BarryCipra the original problem was $m!=100x^2+20x $ Due to my stupidy I called 2 different variables $x $ so I'll call $x$ as in $100x^2$ : $x_1$ so $m!=100x_1^2+20x_1$. Now I knew that I could substitute $x_1$ with $10x+5$ or $10x+10$. First let's substitute  $10x+10$  $m!=100((10x+10)^2)+20(10x+10)$. Expand that & you get $m!/200=50x^2+101x+51$.  We have now 2 equations. The complex idea is that let's write the other equation in the form $ax^2+bx+c$. I think that the $gcd(a,b) $ is 1. I think this is the same as for when you substitute $x $ with $10x+7$ & you simplify you get $gcd(a,b)=1$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76386/discussion-between-pintofmilk-and-barry-cipra).

Comment: @PintOfMilk  You came close to a partial answer by establishing that if the inequality is false, then $(m!+1)=(100x+51)^2$. For $n \le m$, $n\not \mid (m!+1)$. But $(100x+51)\mid (100x+51)^2$. Therefore the inequality is true for $x$ such that $(100x+51) \le m$.

Comment: @KeithBackman I am very sorry but I am not sure this that relevant now - thank you for you answer anyway